# c# context changes with an IF statement

Tags: c#

I'm used to interpretive languages (like PowerShell), but am trying to move to c# as a more structured code and to honestly just learn something new. So in this I've been teaching myself, reading a lot of posts on a lot of forums, watching videos etc.

It seems I'm missing some key piece of knowledge that continually comes up in different methods I write. The more complex the activity, the more of this context issue I see - but while I know it's a context issue, I can't seem to figure out how people work around it (or how to ask google the question the right way to find the answer). So I would appreciate the thoughts of others on the topic, and any wisdom you could impart to me.

Let's say I have a function that looks something like this:

```
    public PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> M2M (int credType, int actionType)
    { 
      //minor secondary question - is my return type valid?

        if (credType == 1)
        {
            PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, txtSingleServer.Text, txtAltCredID.Text, txtAltCredPW.Text);

        }
        else if (credType == 2)
        {
            PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, txtSingleServer.Text);
        }

        UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(context);
        PrincipalSearcher userPrincipalSearcher = new PrincipalSearcher();
        userPrincipalSearcher.QueryFilter = user;
        PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = userPrincipalSearcher.FindAll();
        return results;

    }
```

So obviously I'm trying to change the PrincipalContext based on a parameter that's passed in. But, if I put an If statement around it, it is no longer visible to the remainder of the method.

So... after a lot of thought I came up with another idea: a global class

```
public static class MyGlobals
{
    PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext();
}
```

From here I tried to call MyGlobals.PrincipalContext from the method and tweaking the value of it there. That blew up on me for 2 reasons I believe. First, it didn't have the required data in the (), and second, it didn't appear to be visible from the first method (even though a string in the same class is visible).

I figure I'm missing some basic concept here, but I have not been able to articulate it to google in a way that would bring back this answer. Any help will be appreciated, and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can move the declaration outside of the if statements, then set the variable inside them. This will allow the usage of that variable at a higher scope than just inside of each of the if blocks.

```
PrincipalContext context = null;
if (credType == 1)
{
    context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, txtSingleServer.Text, txtAltCredID.Text, txtAltCredPW.Text);

}
else if (credType == 2)
{
    context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, txtSingleServer.Text);
}
```

Comment: It would not compile in this form though. `context` has to be initialized in all program paths.

Comment: If you have your IDE set to error instead of warning for this, you are correct. Error handling was not part of this question though.

Comment: @NathanWerry This is not a warning in C#, it is always an error. `context` must be definitely assigned before it's used since it is a local variable (as opposed to a class field which is default initialized to `null` which would likely cause a runtime error).